# WPF user-editable config file

Tags: wpf

I'd like the users of my touch app to be able to modify certain UserControl properties by editing a text or XML file (e.g border colors and thicknesses, that sort of thing).

What's the best way to include a file like that in my project so that users can edit it after it's been published? I think if they go in the app.config file they're not editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.config is editable, but should only be edited by an admin in the event that system settings change in a way that makes the deployment settings no longer applicable.

Prefer instead to used a settings file.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) seems to be the standard method of handling it.