# Where are the default values in .settings files stored for .NET 6 WPF apps?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, settings, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 WPF desktop app that uses several .settings files for managing user settings but the user can't manage the settings because I don't know where the default values are stored.

If I change a value in code at runtime:

```cs
FontSettings.FontFamily=someFont;
FontSettings.Save();
```

only then do I get a settings file generated in `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\{AppName}\{Version}\blaBla.config`, but even then, it only writes the value that I manually changed in code so I have to guess what are the names of the other values.

If I don't change any value in code, the file just isn't being generated. How is a user supposed to change the default values? Decompile the app?

Some other questions that you might think are duplicates suggest that these settings are in an `appConfig.config` file or other some such. I don't know what .net version they're using but I don't have such a file in my project.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the value not using the getter of the property?

Comment: Why do you think I'm not using the getter?

Comment: Do you want to access the default value regardless of the current value?

Comment: I am able to access the value from code just fine. What I want is to allow the user to modify these values by simply opening a text file. What text file is the user supposed to open before the app decides to generate those config files in the app data folder? If it decides to generate them at all.

Comment: The user is not supposed to open that file directly at all. You decided to use settings. Now you find settings are not suitable.  Don't use settings if you want the user to over write data in notepad.

Comment: @Andy well, at least two stack exchange answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613988/wpf-user-editable-config-file), [two](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191419/configuration-file-that-can-be-modified-by-user-in-c)) seem to suggest that you could do just that. Besides, the biggest advantage to using these is that I can add them as a resource in XAML and bind to them directly.

Comment: You need to open your text editor as admin to edit anything in program files. Do your  users all have machine admin? That is not usual in businesses I've worked in.

Comment: @Andy [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-setting-between-application-sessions?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is even a link from 2022 which specifies, and I quote, "At times, you might want to change the value of a setting between application sessions after the application has been compiled and deployed. [...]  Using Microsoft Notepad or some other text or XML editor, open the .config file associated with your application." Where the heck is this file supposed to be? Doesn't say, in true MSDN documentation fashion.

Comment: It's next to your compiled exe.

Comment: Which will end up under program files. Which is why the edited version ends up in appdata. Because a lot of business users just won't have admin rights.

Comment: @Andy The problem isn't with program files. The app is installed in the app data folder. Heck, apart from the settings file, I can send you the published app as a zip folder with all the binaries and you can run it from wherever you want.

Comment: @Andy "It's next to your compiled exe." That's just it. It isn't. No config file anywhere in the entire solution, as I said in the question. No config file in the publish folder, no config file in the solution folder, no config file in bin\Release\net6.0-windows folder.

Comment: The only config file I have is the appsettings.json, but this isn't the .settings file I am talking about.

Comment: I suggest you try a scratch solution. If that still doesn't behave as I describe mine does then maybe  reset visual studio settings.

Comment: Your suggestion did the trick. In a fresh new solution / project, everything works as intended and as you described. Moved the code to the new project and now the app config gets generated and whatever changes I make in the .settings files are automatically synced in the app config. Marked your post as the answer since, well, that's the answer. Don't know why it didn't worked in the original project.

Comment: Does seem a bit weird. Since VS is working as expected I guess it's something in your sln or csproj.  FWIW I've never been much of a fan of the settings mechanism. (You probably noticed.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you add a settings file and set a value on a setting in it, you should also find an app.config is added in the root of your project.

When I try that in a solution I have I see these files in git changes

[image]

I did not add app.config myself but it only appeared when I added settings1 and then saved a setting in it.

Mine looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="XXXXXXX.Settings1" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <XXXXX.Settings1>
            <setting name="fooo" serializeAs="String">
                <value>bar</value>
            </setting>
        </XXXXX.Settings1>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ok, I added a new settings file and I see this single config file but I don't have any of the values. Just
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```
Do I need to configure anything in the properties of this file or the .settings files? And yes, I did add values to the settings file. At this point I'm starting to think my project is corrupt or something.